# How to find the limit of a sin function

Tags: limits

Evaluate

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin(8x)}{−8x}$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin(−4x)}{−7x}$
3. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin(−4x)}{1x}$

Is the limit for $x\rightarrow 0$ for these functions undefined, i.e. $\frac{0}{0}$?

Please explain.

Comment: Did you ever heard of the fundamental limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Comment: No. I'm very new to calculus. Could you explain why lim x->0 sinx/x =1?

Comment: You can find a proof in any good calculus book, but you can think that for small angles $\sin x\approx x$, then the result follows, but it is not a formal answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Answer (score 6):

Follow what DiegoMath wrote.

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1
$$

whence

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{bx} = \frac{a}{b} \lim_{ax \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{ax} = \frac{a}{b}, a \ne 0, b \ne 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) when both the numerator and denominator are 0 at the limit point, and both are differentiable.

$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\sin ax}{bx}=\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{a\cos ax}{b}=\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: Invoking L'H to evaluate the limit of $\sin x/x$ when $x\to0$ is litterally absurd, as has been explained several times on the site.